# Choosing host from inventory group based on a host variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have an ansible inventory file that looks like this:

```
[web]
web1.so.com tech=apache
web2.so.com tech=nginx
```

I'd like to list the web hosts in a config file only if the tech is nginx. So in this case i'd like the ansible template to produce the below in the config file.

`server: web2.so.com`

How can I get ansible to insert web hosts only if tech=nginx?

I would usually access hosts by setting using groups in the ansible template:

`server: "{{groups['web']}}"`

But i'm aware this will list all of the hosts in the web group.

I can't figure out how to only choose hosts that have `tech=nginx`, and in this use case it's not possible to split them up into web-nginx and web-apache groups.

It's also not possible to hardcode it to use web2 as the apache host could change with each rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups dynamically with the [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) or [`group_by`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html) modules.

In your case, using `group_by` as in the following example should meet your requirements:

```
---
- name: Create dynamic tech groups
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create the groups depending on tech
      group_by:
        key: "tech_{{ tech }}"
      when: tech is defined

- name: Do something on nginx group
  hosts: tech_nginx
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show it works
      debug:
        msg: "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Of course, once this is done, you can use `groups['tech_nginx']` elsewhere in your playbook to get the list of hosts in that group.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"List the web hosts in a config file only if the tech is nginx."*

A: It is possible to use *json_query*. For example the play below

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        nginx_list: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                        json_query('[?value.tech==`nginx`].key') }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: nginx_list
```

gives the variable *nginx_list* which can be used in the configuration.

```
ok: [web1.so.com] => {
    "nginx_list": [
        "web2.so.com"
    ]
}
ok: [web2.so.com] => {
    "nginx_list": [
        "web2.so.com"
    ]
}
```

For example *lineinfile* below

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/webservers.cfg
    regex: "^nginx\\s*=(.*)$"
    line: "nginx = {{ nginx_list|join(', ') }}"
    create: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```
$ cat /tmp/webservers.cfg 
nginx = web2.so.com
```